# Trying to split string on occurrence of double $$ charter in java

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I need to split my string with any occurrence of $$ for this string:

```
String tmpHash = "NA$notValid-1$notValid-2##notValid-3##$$VALID-1##$$VALID-2##$notvalid-4$$VALID-3";
```

Here is my code:

```
String[] arr=tmpHash.split("$$");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("OUTPUT--> "+arr[i]);    

        }
```

**OUTPUT IS**

```
OUTPUT--> NA$notValid-1$notValid-2##notValid-3##$$VALID-1##$$VALID-2##$notvalid-4$$VALID-3
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
OUTPUT-->NA$notValid-1$notValid-2##notValid-3##
OUTPUT-->VALID-1##
OUTPUT-->VALID-2##$notvalid-4
OUTPUT-->VALID-3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and short answer for splitting string having $$ is 
here we will be escaping $ because it is used in regex internally.

```
String[] arr=tmpHash.split("\\$\\$");
```

Answer (score 5):

You would have to escape the `$` sign.

```
String[] arr=tmpHash.split("\\$\\$");
```

Or use (according to [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853726/java-regular-expressions-and-dollar-sign/3853764#3853764))

```
String myString = "$$";
String escapedString = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(myString)
```

to [automatically escape all special regex characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) in a given string.

Comment: @ravz So it seems strange you didn't accept this answer then...

Comment: @AntonH Although your final paragraph looks rather similar to the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3853764/474189). If you "borrowed" it, you should probably give credit where it's due.

Comment: @Duncan I didn't know how to reference an answer, and then got distracted . My apologies. Edited to reference answer.