# String#replaceAll() method not replacing for $ (dollar)

Tags: java

I've tried built-in method **String#replaceAll()** to replace all **"$"** from my String content. But it's not working.

```
String ss = "HELLO_$_JAVA";
System.out.println(ss.indexOf("$"));
System.out.println(ss);
ss = ss.replaceAll("$", "");
System.out.println(ss);// 'HELLO__JAVA' is expected
```

OUTPUT:

```
6
HELLO_$_JAVA
HELLO_$_JAVA
```

Expected output:

```
6
HELLO_$_JAVA
HELLO__JAVA
```

**EDIT:**
Although [Java regular expressions and dollar sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853726/java-regular-expressions-and-dollar-sign) covers the answer, but still my question may be helpful for someone who is facing same problem when using **String#replaceAll()**.
And 
[Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceal) also may be helpful.

Two possible solution of that question is

```
ss = ss.replace("$", "");
```

OR

```
ss = ss.replaceAll("\\$", "");
```

Comment: Why should `HELLO_$_JAVA` be the expected output? Where should the `_` come from?

Comment: I find it very weird that the `"HELLO$JAVA"` string is being printed as `HELLO_$_JAVA`

Comment: like hinted by the previous comments, your code does not match the output you've shown. That's not the way it works.

Comment: Replace all uses a Regex. Use Pattern.quote("$").

Comment: Lot of DOWNVAOTE ... I didn't expect :-o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is for regular expressions. `'$'` is a special character in regular expressions.

If you are not trying to use regular expressions, use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), NOT [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 9):

The first parameter of the `replaceAll` method takes a *regular expression*, not a literal string, and `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions.

You need to escape the `$` by putting a backslash in front of it; and the backslash needs to be double because it has a special meaning in Java string literals.

```
ss = ss.replaceAll("\\$", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

May be not the best way but a work around,

```
String parts[] = ss.split("\\$");
```

Then concat each of them

```
String output = "";
for(String each:parts){
    output=output+each;
}
```

Then you have your replaced string in **output**

Comment: why should op do this?

Comment: @eis Just a work around.

Comment: quite over the top, instead of using the regex for a split on `$` and concatination the array back he could have just replaced it with the correct regex in the first place.